# Missing php_yaml.dll file

Tags: php, dll, xampp, yaml

I'm using XAMPP with PHP 5.5.27 PHP and Windows 10 (x64). I'm triyng to install the `YAML` extention. [Link from other topic](http://search.4shared.com/postDownload/ComqwjFvce/php_yaml-102-dev-54-vc9-x86.html) is dead so I dowloaded files version PHP 5.5, x64, TS and NTS.
I placed file `php_yaml.dll` into `c:\xampp\php\ext` and `yaml.dll` files into `c:\xampp\`.
Then I added entry `extension=php_yaml.dll` just after `extension=php_xsl.dll` (as last entry of Dynamic Extensions.
At the end I restarted Apache.

Result is:

> phpinfo() doesn't display info about YAML extention.

Comment: You want the Thread Safe(TS) version and as to 32/64bit it should match your XAMPP version rather than your OS version so if you have a 32bit XAMPP you need the 32bit `php_yaml.dll` Also you should only need to place it in the `c:\xampp\php\ext` folder

Answer (score 1):

You want the Thread Safe(TS) version and as to 32/64bit it should match your XAMPP version rather than your OS version so if you have a 32bit XAMPP you need the 32bit php_yaml.dll Also you should only need to place it in the c:\xampp\php\ext folder

Also remember that there are 2 `php.ini` files. One in the `c:\xampp\apache\bin` folder that Apache uses and one in `c:\xampp\php\php.ini`, it is this one that controls PHP's config when being used from the CLI (Command Line Interface) So you also need to add the `extension=php_yaml.dll` to this `php.ini` file as well if you want command line PHP to load this extension.

To check which php.ini file is being loaded in the CLI do this from the command line

```
php -ini | more
```

Look for this entry

```
Loaded Configuration File => D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\php.ini
```

Check that yours says something sensible for your system

Comment: Did you add the `extension=php_yaml.dll` to the `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` file? Also check the `extension_dir` in this `php.ini` is set correctly!

Comment: There is only one php.ini in my xampp.

Comment: Then try copying the one from the apache folder to the php folder see if that works

Comment: I did. Now i have two same file php.ini in **c:\xampp\php\** and **c:\xampp\apache\bin\**. Path entry `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"` is correct. PHP works correctly but always shows this warning. And Loaded Configuration File => C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: Hmmmm I am stumped then

Comment: Have you tried this using a command window rather than power shell

Comment: Yes, in CMD. Maybe this: when i use `phpinfo()` then i see info about `YAML` but there's no information about it when i run `php -ini | more`.